# Copy only new entries from one database table to another. Access, C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am trying to create an application with a list of messages that users hide for themself, without affecting others.
I thought the easiest way to do this would be to have a main database with all the messages and a user copy of this with extra columns such as hidden (bool)
I can almost get this to work but cannot find  a way to not copy emtries that already exist while keeping the additional boolean values already stored.

Basically, how do you copy only entries of a database table that don't exist in the other one.

I tried to use left join (SELECT messages.Message, user.Hidden FROM messages LEFT JOIN user ON messages.Message = user.Message) but I'm not sure if this works as it gives me an error (Syntax error in FROM clause)

An example:

messages DB:

message

m1
m2
m3

Initially user database is empty, when first run should create:

message....hidden

m1.................F

m2.................F

m3.................F

Say the user hid all the messages, then messages DB changed to:

message

m1

m3

m4

m5

User database changes to

message....Hidden

m1................T

m3................T

m4................F

m5................F

I am using Access and C#, first time doing anything with databases, sorry if this is a pretty stupid question, couldn't find anyone else asking the same thing. Also, if I'm going about this in completely the wrong way I wouldn't mind ideas for a better method, though in the actual application there will be more columns in both databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the nicest method but at least I got it working. Left join does work, I think the problem before was that user was a reserved word

```
"SELECT messages.message, [User].hidden INTO temp FROM messages LEFT JOIN [User] ON messages.message = [User].message;"

"DROP table [User]"

"SELECT * INTO [User] FROM temp;"
```

Of course, if anyone knows a nicer implementation, especially one that avoids the need for a temporary table, I would like to see it.